# Error "2 not defined because of singularities" in a regression BUT is not because of collinearity

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

My data set is stored in "monthly". This dataset is pretty large (1812 rows x 28 columns).
I tried to do a linear regression with 15 dependent variables as the following:

```
modelKS <- lm(log_eqpt1 ~ dp + dy + ep + de + svar + csp + b.m + ntis + tbl + lty + ltr + tms + dfy + dfr + infl, data = monthly)
```

[image]

When I run `summary(modelKS)` I get the following error: "2 not defined because of singularities". These 2 variables that get NAs are "de" and "tms"

I checked with the vif() function but the result is way lower than 5. Moreover, the correlation function `cor(monthly$de, monthly$tms, use = "complete.obs")`, gives a value of 0.1483532.

Therefore, it looks like that the correlation is not the problem.
How could I solve this? I would like to keep both variable in the multiple regression.
Thanks

After suggestion from one of you, I tried `cor(model.matrix(modelKS))` and I attach here the output

[image]

Comment: while de and tms are not collinear, it could be that these variables be collinear to someother. You must check for example `cor(model.matrix(modelKS))` for collinear variables outside diagonal.

Comment: @Ric Hi Ric thanks for your comment. I ran the check suggested by you and I uploaded the output on the main question. What is your suggestion now? Many thanks

Comment: Well it's not easy with no data. summary output also says there are 1024 removed rows with missingness (NA). Try cor(model.matrix(modelKS), na.rm=TRUE) for finding ones outside diagonals, if not, try removing higly collinear variables from the model like "dy" or "dp" (one of two).